# Xamarin forms Grid with radius and background color

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I am  developing an app for UWP using xamarin forms.

I need create a screen like this

[image]

For UWP but I don't know how do it the Grid with Radius and backgrondcolor .

I try it with a frame but when I add the BackgroundColor property the Radius disappears.

I try with https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/RoundedBoxView but don't work for UWP.

Thank you so much

**UPDATE: SOLUTION**

I find the solution. Make a custom render of Frame for UWP.

Here's the code : https://github.com/migueBarrera/XamarinRoundedFrame with the final image

Comment: Use Frame and set background color to Grid not frame

Comment: @ZiyadGodil i try but this is the result : https://imgur.com/bVvbGHd

Answer (score 0):

You should try Frame instead of boxview and if you want to use grid than you have to make custom renderer for the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Frame seems to work well, at least on Android.

This is my XAML

```
<Frame BackgroundColor="LawnGreen" 
        CornerRadius="25"
        VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
        Margin="20">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Entry"/>
        <Label Text="Entry"/>
        <Label Text="Entry"/>
        <Button Text="Entrar" Margin="10, 30, 10, 20"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

And this is the page

[image]

Comment: I copy your code and this is the result in UWP : https://imgur.com/bVvbGHd . The Radius disappears.

Comment: @MiguelAngelMuñoz Replace the `Frame` for a `BoxView`. I guess the `CornerRadius` property is something like `BorderRadius`.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza I try with BoxView but I can't find any property like BorderRadius or CornerRadius

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. The `BorderRadius` property is of the `Button` view. Check if a custom renderer based implementation [like this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31244/box-view-with-rounded-corners-badge-with-counter-snippets) can do the trick for you (those example shows implementation to Android and Ios, but not UWP)